# Can the cCurl algorithm run on an Arduino?

Tags: curl, arduino

Has anyone tried running cCurl on a microcontroller, such as Arduino or ESP8266? So that microcontrollers can do the Proof of Work. Would this even be efficient? I know how the algorithm works (hashing until hash has 14 trailing zeroes), but I don't know how computationally expensive it is and if it can fit onto a 512k - 4MB microcontroller.